# JSON.stringify serializes to [[]]

Tags: javascript, json

If I create a JavaScript object like:

```
var lst = [];
var row = [];
row.Col1 = 'val1';
row.Col2 = 'val2'; 
lst.push(row);
```

And then convert it to a string:

```
JSON.stringify(lst);
```

The result is an object containing an empty object:

```
[[]]
```

I would expect it to serialize like:

```
[[Col1 : 'val1', Col2: 'val2']]
```

Why do the inner objects properties not serialize?

[Code snippet at JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/3nvMF/)

Comment: Visit http://json.org. You'll see that JSON has 2 structures. One allows key/value pairs, the other is a simple ordered list. JavaScript objects serialize to key/value pairs, and JavaScript arrays serialize to the ordered list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `row` is an array, not an object. Change it to:

```
var row = {};
```

This creates an object literal. Your code will then result in an array of objects (containing a single object):

```
[{"Col1":"val1","Col2":"val2"}]
```

**Update**

To see what really happens, you can look at [json2.js on GitHub](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js). This is a (heavily reduced) snippet from the `str` function (called by `JSON.stringify`):

```
if (Object.prototype.toString.apply(value) === '[object Array]') {
    //...
    length = value.length;
    for (i = 0; i < length; i += 1) {
        partial[i] = str(i, value) || 'null';
    }
    //...
}
//...
for (k in value) {
    if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(value, k)) {
        //...
    }
    //...
}
//...
```

Notice that arrays are iterated over with a normal `for` loop, which only enumerates the array elements. Objects are iterated with a `for...in` loop, with a `hasOwnProperty` test to make sure the proeprty actually belongs to this object.

Comment: So an array only serializes its 1,2,3 keys, and not a random name like val1?

Comment: The contents of the array will be serialized. When you try to assign a value to a property of an array object, it doesn't actually get added to the array.

Comment: Well, the property is added in the sense that it becomes visible in the debugger.

Comment: Yes, it's added to the object (that instance of `Array`), but `JSON.stringify` will only serialize the contents of the array, and not arbitrary properties of the object (otherwise you'd also get things like the `length` property).

Comment: @Andomar - I've updated my answer with some more detail of what's actually going on behind the scenes.

Answer (score 3):

You use your inner array like an object, so make it an object instead of an array.

```
var lst = [];
var row = {};
row.Col1 = 'val1';
row.Col2 = 'val2'; 
lst.push(row);
```

or use it as an array

```
var lst = [];
var row = {};
row.push( 'val1' );
row.push( 'val2' );
lst.push(row);
```

Comment: Thanks, upvoted!  It was the answer from James that made me see `{}` is an object and `[]` is an array

Answer (score 1):

You want row to be a dictionary, not a vector. Define it like this:

```
var row = {};
```

Answer (score 1):

Since an array is a datatype in JSON, actual instances of `Array` are stringified differently than other object types.

If a JavaScript `Array` instance got stringified with its non-numeric keys intact, it couldn't be represented by the `[ ... ]` JSON array syntax.

For instance, `[ "Col1": "val1"]` would be invalid, because JSON arrays can't have explicit keys.
`{"Col1": "val1"}` would be valid - but it's not an array.

And you certainly can't mix'n'match and get `{ "Col1": "val1", 1, 2, 3 ]` or something.

By the way, this works fine:

```
var lst = [];
var row = {};
row.Col1 = 'val1';
row.Col2 = 'val2'; 
lst.push(row);
alert(JSON.stringify(lst));​
```